# Как сделать анимацию кнопки в стиле spark?

Tags: javascript, css, css3, svg, css-animation

Я только что нашел на [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/frogermcs/LikeAnimation),  отличную анимация для кнопки, но она сделана только для `Android`.

Вот эта анимация:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тем не менее, я хочу такую же кнопку для своего сайта, поэтому я начал разрабатывать это сам.

Во-первых, я разбил [гифку по кадрам](https://ezgif.com/maker/ezgif-1-672b08ae8c62-gif-im/ezgif-1-672b08ae8c62.gif).

И затем по этим кадрам я составил дорожную карту, которой я следую при написании кода:

- Звезда постепенно `scale()` уменьшается.
- Маленький кружок оранжевого цвета постепенно покрывает звезду при
  увеличении.
- Еще один маленький кружок, но на этот раз цвета фона (в данном случае
  белый), постепенно перекрывает  предыдущий кружок также увеличением
  масштаба.
- Наряду с этим звезда также постепенно увеличивается снова и снова
  появляясь (таким образом, я должен увеличить `z-index`), на этот раз
  оранжевого цвета (Указывая на ее выбранное состояние).
- Есть еще маленькие кружочки, разбросанные со всех сторон новой
  звезды.

**Это то, что получилось у меня:**

```css
svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  fill:gray;
}

svg:hover {
  animation: up-svg 1s;
  fill: darkorange;
  z-index: 1;
}

svg:hover~.svg {
  animation: up-one 0.5s;
  display: block;
}

svg:hover~.svg1 {
  animation: up-two 1s;
  display: block;
}

.svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  display: none;
  transform: scale(0.9);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.svg1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  display: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

@keyframes up-one {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }
}

@keyframes up-two {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  37.5% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.25);
  }
  62.5% {
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  75% {
    transform: scale(0.75);
  }
  87.5% {
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes up-svg {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    fill: gray;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(0);
    fill: darkorange;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    fill: darkorange;
    z-index: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="s-tt" class="s-icon" role="img" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M23.954 4.569c-.885.389-1.83.654-2.825.775 1.014-.611 1.794-1.574 2.163-2.723-.951.555-2.005.959-3.127 1.184-.896-.959-2.173-1.559-3.591-1.559-2.717 0-4.92 2.203-4.92 4.917 0 .39.045.765.127 1.124C7.691 8.094 4.066 6.13 1.64 3.161c-.427.722-.666 1.561-.666 2.475 0 1.71.87 3.213 2.188 4.096-.807-.026-1.566-.248-2.228-.616v.061c0 2.385 1.693 4.374 3.946 4.827-.413.111-.849.171-1.296.171-.314 0-.615-.03-.916-.086.631 1.953 2.445 3.377 4.604 3.417-1.68 1.319-3.809 2.105-6.102 2.105-.39 0-.779-.023-1.17-.067 2.189 1.394 4.768 2.209 7.557 2.209 9.054 0 13.999-7.496 13.999-13.986 0-.209 0-.42-.015-.63.961-.689 1.8-1.56 2.46-2.548l-.047-.02z"/></svg>
<div class="svg"></div>
<div class="svg1"></div>
```

Я пробовал, но все же результат не похож на ожидаемый, и я застрял с этими кругами рассеяния тоже.
Цвета не являются приоритетом прямо сейчас. И я придерживаюсь свойства `hover` (чтобы анимация была видна снова и снова без перезагрузки), пока анимация не будет доведена до конца.

Я искал решения в `Google` и `SO`, но пока не повезло.
Итак, кто-нибудь поможет мне  сделать такую анимацию?

**UPDATE**

Добавляю ссылку на [spark анимацию](https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/xwJmgv) от известного мастера **Ana Tudor**

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/54593203/7394871

Answer (score 8):

Вот моя не идеальная идея, где я буду полагаться только на `CSS` и немного элементов. Я подробно опишу каждую часть, а затем объединю это в одну анимацию.

Для части с иконкой (звездочкой) я бы сделал то же самое, как у вас, но я, вероятно, рассмотрю фильтр в оттенках серого, чтобы иметь общий эффект, который работает с любым элементом и любым цветом.

```css
.magic i{
  color:red;
  filter:grayscale(100%);
}
.magic:hover i{
  animation:change 1s forwards;
}


@keyframes change{
  50% {
    transform:scale(0);
  filter:grayscale(100%);
  }
  51% {
    filter:grayscale(0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform:scale(1);
    filter:grayscale(0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css">
<span class="magic">
<i class="fas fa-star fa-5x"></i>
</span>
```

Для круга я рассмотрю только один элемент, и хитрость здесь заключается в том, чтобы полагаться на окраску `border` по сравнению с окраской `background`.

Мы изначально устанавливаем `height/width` равной нулю, и у нас есть только `border`, поэтому это будет полный круг.

Затем мы просто уменьшаем толщину `border`, сохраняя общую ширину одинаковой. Итак, мы сделаем:

1. Начальная форма `width/height` - `0` and `border-width` - `0`
2. Мы увеличиваем `border-width`, чтобы создать эффект увеличения
3. Мы уменьшаем `border-width`, увеличивая при этом `width/height`, чтобы сохранить общую `width/height` одинаковой.

```css
.circle {
  display:inline-block;
  width:0px;
  height:0px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border-color:orange;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:0px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

body:hover .circle {
  animation:change 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes change {
   50% {
    border-width:25px;
   }
   100% {
    border-width:0;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
   }

}

body {
 min-height:100px;
}
```

```html
<span class="circle"></span>
```

Это решение имеет небольшой недостаток, так как элемент будет увеличиваться сверху слева, а не по центру. Мы можем исправить это, используя `scale` вместо изменения `width/height`:

```css
.circle {
  display:inline-block;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border-color:orange;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:25px;
  transform:scale(0);
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

body:hover .circle {
  animation:change 1s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes change {
   50% {
    transform:scale(1);
    border-width:25px;
   }
   100% {
    transform:scale(1);
    border-width:0;
   }

}

body {
 min-height:100px;
}
```

```html
<span class="circle"></span>
```

Мы  можем упростить рассмотрение простого `transition`:

```css
.circle {
  display:inline-block;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border-color:orange;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:25px;
  transform:scale(0);
  box-sizing:border-box;
  transition:
    transform 0.5s,
    border-width 0.5s 0.5s;
}

body:hover .circle {
  border-width:0;
  transform:scale(1);
}

body {
 min-height:100px;
}
```

```html
<span class="circle"></span>
```

Теперь сложная часть анимации и добавление маленьких кругов. Для этого я буду полагаться на `radial-gradient` и `scale`. Идея состоит в том, чтобы создать маленькие круги с градиентом внутри одного элемента, и используя `scale`, мы создадим эффект их увеличения и движения.

```css
.small {
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:
    /*4 reds*/
    radial-gradient(circle,red 50%,transparent 60%),
    radial-gradient(circle,red 50%,transparent 60%),
    radial-gradient(circle,red 50%,transparent 60%),
    radial-gradient(circle,red 50%,transparent 60%),
    /*4 oranges*/
    radial-gradient(circle,orange 50%,transparent 60%),
    radial-gradient(circle,orange 50%,transparent 60%),
    radial-gradient(circle,orange 50%,transparent 60%),
    radial-gradient(circle,orange 50%,transparent 60%); 
  
  background-size:16px 16px; 
  background-position:
    calc(50% - 30px) calc(50% - 30px),
    calc(50% + 30px) calc(50% - 30px),
    calc(50% - 30px) calc(50% + 30px),
    calc(50% + 30px) calc(50% + 30px),
    calc(50% +  0px) calc(50% + 40px),
    calc(50% + 40px) calc(50% +  0px),
    calc(50% - 40px) calc(50% +  0px),
    calc(50% +  0px) calc(50% - 40px);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<span class="small"></span>
```

Я создал 8 кругов и разместил их, смещая их от центра (посмотрите этот ответ, чтобы узнать больше о том, как работает `background-position`:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51734530/8620333

Вам просто нужно настроить размер, положение и цвет круга, как вам необходимо.

А вот с анимацией:

```css
.small {
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:
    /*4 reds*/
    radial-gradient(circle,red 50%,transparent 60%),
    radial-gradient(circle,red 50%,transparent 60%),
    radial-gradient(circle,red 50%,transparent 60%),
    radial-gradient(circle,red 50%,transparent 60%),
    /*4 oranges*/
    radial-gradient(circle,orange 50%,transparent 60%),
    radial-gradient(circle,orange 50%,transparent 60%),
    radial-gradient(circle,orange 50%,transparent 60%),
    radial-gradient(circle,orange 50%,transparent 60%); 
  
  background-size:16px 16px;
  background-position:
    calc(50% - 30px) calc(50% - 30px),
    calc(50% + 30px) calc(50% - 30px),
    calc(50% - 30px) calc(50% + 30px),
    calc(50% + 30px) calc(50% + 30px),
    calc(50% +  0px) calc(50% + 40px),
    calc(50% + 40px) calc(50% +  0px),
    calc(50% - 40px) calc(50% +  0px),
    calc(50% +  0px) calc(50% - 40px);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  border-radius:50%;
  transform:scale(0);
  transition:transform 0.5s,opacity 0.4s 0.4s;
}

body {
 min-height:200px;
}
body:hover .small {
  transform:scale(1);
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<span class="small"></span>
```

Если вы хотите более точную анимацию, вы также можете уменьшить круги, уменьшив `background-size`.

```css
.small {
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:
    /*4 reds*/
    radial-gradient(circle,red 50%,transparent 60%),
    radial-gradient(circle,red 50%,transparent 60%),
    radial-gradient(circle,red 50%,transparent 60%),
    radial-gradient(circle,red 50%,transparent 60%),
    /*4 oranges*/
    radial-gradient(circle,orange 50%,transparent 60%),
    radial-gradient(circle,orange 50%,transparent 60%),
    radial-gradient(circle,orange 50%,transparent 60%),
    radial-gradient(circle,orange 50%,transparent 60%); 
  
  background-size:16px 16px; /*at least 2x7px */
  background-position:
    calc(50% - 30px) calc(50% - 30px),
    calc(50% + 30px) calc(50% - 30px),
    calc(50% - 30px) calc(50% + 30px),
    calc(50% + 30px) calc(50% + 30px),
    calc(50% +  0px) calc(50% + 40px),
    calc(50% + 40px) calc(50% +  0px),
    calc(50% - 40px) calc(50% +  0px),
    calc(50% +  0px) calc(50% - 40px);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  border-radius:50%;
  transform:scale(0);
  transition:transform 0.5s,opacity 0.4s 0.4s,background-size 0.5s 0.4s;
}

body {
 min-height:200px;
}
body:hover .small {
  transform:scale(1);
  opacity:0;
  background-size:0 0;
}
```

```html
<span class="small"></span>
```

Теперь вы просто делаете то же самое с другими маленькими кружками, изменяя некоторые значения.

### Давайте соединим все это!

```css
.magic {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:50px;
  position:relative;
}

.magic i{
  color:orange;
  filter:grayscale(100%);
  position:relative;
}
.magic:hover i{
  animation:change 1s forwards;
}


@keyframes change{
  50% {
    transform:scale(0);
  filter:grayscale(100%);
  }
  51% {
    filter:grayscale(0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform:scale(1);
    filter:grayscale(0%);
  }
}
/**/

.magic:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:calc(50% - 45px);
  left:calc(50% - 45px);
  width:90px;
  height:90px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border-color:orange;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:45px;
  transform:scale(0);
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.magic:hover::before {
  transition:
    transform 0.5s,
    border-width 0.5s 0.5s;
  border-width:0;
  transform:scale(1);
}

/**/

.magic::after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  width:160px;
  height:160px;
  left:calc(50% - 80px);
  top:calc(50% - 80px);
  background:
    /*4 reds*/
    radial-gradient(circle,red 50%,transparent 60%),
    radial-gradient(circle,red 50%,transparent 60%),
    radial-gradient(circle,red 50%,transparent 60%),
    radial-gradient(circle,red 50%,transparent 60%),
    /*4 oranges*/
    radial-gradient(circle,orange 50%,transparent 60%),
    radial-gradient(circle,orange 50%,transparent 60%),
    radial-gradient(circle,orange 50%,transparent 60%),
    radial-gradient(circle,orange 50%,transparent 60%); 
  
  background-size:16px 16px; 
  background-position:
    calc(50% - 50px) calc(50% - 50px),
    calc(50% + 50px) calc(50% - 50px),
    calc(50% - 50px) calc(50% + 50px),
    calc(50% + 50px) calc(50% + 50px),
    calc(50% +  0px) calc(50% + 70px),
    calc(50% + 70px) calc(50% +  0px),
    calc(50% - 70px) calc(50% +  0px),
    calc(50% +  0px) calc(50% - 70px);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  border-radius:50%;
  transform:scale(0);
}

.magic:hover:after {
  transform:scale(1);
  opacity:0;
  background-size:0 0;
  transition:
    transform 0.5s 0.5s,
    opacity 0.4s 0.9s,
    background-size 0.5s 0.9s;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css">
<span class="magic">
<i class="fas fa-star fa-5x"></i>
</span>

<span class="magic">
<i class="fas fa-user fa-5x"></i>
</span>
```

Как я уже сказал, он не идеален, но очень близок к тому, что вы хотите, с меньшим количеством элементов и необходимыми деталями, так что вы можете легко настроить различные значения.

Я не добавил крошечные круги для простоты, но мы можем рассмотреть другой псевдоэлемент и легко добавить их:

```css
.magic {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:50px;
  position:relative;
}

.magic i{
  color:orange;
  filter:grayscale(100%);
}
.magic:hover i{
  animation:change 1s forwards;
}


@keyframes change{
  50% {
    transform:scale(0);
  filter:grayscale(100%);
  }
  51% {
    filter:grayscale(0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform:scale(1);
    filter:grayscale(0%);
  }
}
/**/

.magic:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:calc(50% - 45px);
  left:calc(50% - 45px);
  width:90px;
  height:90px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border-color:orange;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:45px;
  transform:scale(0);
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.magic:hover::before {
  border-width:0;
  transform:scale(1);
  transition:
    transform 0.5s,
    border-width 0.5s 0.5s;
}

/**/

.magic::after,
.magic i::after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  width:160px;
  height:160px;
  left:calc(50% - 80px);
  top:calc(50% - 80px);
  background:
    /*4 reds*/
    radial-gradient(circle,red 50%,transparent 60%),
    radial-gradient(circle,red 50%,transparent 60%),
    radial-gradient(circle,red 50%,transparent 60%),
    radial-gradient(circle,red 50%,transparent 60%),
    /*4 oranges*/
    radial-gradient(circle,orange 50%,transparent 60%),
    radial-gradient(circle,orange 50%,transparent 60%),
    radial-gradient(circle,orange 50%,transparent 60%),
    radial-gradient(circle,orange 50%,transparent 60%); 
  
  background-size:16px 16px; 
  background-position:
    calc(50% - 50px) calc(50% - 50px),
    calc(50% + 50px) calc(50% - 50px),
    calc(50% - 50px) calc(50% + 50px),
    calc(50% + 50px) calc(50% + 50px),
    calc(50% +  0px) calc(50% + 70px),
    calc(50% + 70px) calc(50% +  0px),
    calc(50% - 70px) calc(50% +  0px),
    calc(50% +  0px) calc(50% - 70px);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  border-radius:50%;
  transform:scale(0);
}
.magic i::after {
  background-size:10px 10px;
  transform:rotate(10deg) scale(0);
}

.magic:hover:after {
  transform:scale(1);
  opacity:0;
  background-size:0 0;
  transition:transform 0.5s 0.5s,opacity 0.4s 0.9s,background-size 0.5s 0.9s;
}
.magic:hover i:after {
  transform:rotate(10deg) scale(1);
  opacity:0;
  background-size:0 0;
  transition:transform 0.5s 0.5s,opacity 0.4s 0.9s,background-size 0.5s 0.9s;
}

/**/
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css">
<span class="magic">
<i class="fas fa-star fa-5x"></i>
</span>

<span class="magic">
<i class="fas fa-user fa-5x"></i>
</span>
```

**UPDATE**

Вот улучшение кода, учитывающее некоторую переменную CSS и использующее более гибкий модуль для простого управления позиционированием:

```css
.magic {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:50px;
  position:relative;
  --r:45px;
}

.magic i{
  color:orange;
  filter:grayscale(100%);
}
.magic:hover i{
  animation:change 1s forwards;
}


@keyframes change{
  50% {
   transform:scale(0);
   filter:grayscale(100%);
  }
  51% {
    filter:grayscale(0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform:scale(1);
    filter:grayscale(0%);
  }
}
/**/

.magic:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:calc(50% - var(--r));
  left:calc(50% - var(--r));
  width:calc(2*var(--r));
  height:calc(2*var(--r));
  border-radius:50%;
  border:solid orange var(--r);
  transform:scale(0);
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.magic:hover::before {
  border-width:0;
  transform:scale(1);
  transition:
    transform 0.5s,
    border-width 0.5s 0.5s;
}

/**/

.magic::after,
.magic i::after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  width: calc(4*var(--r));
  height:calc(4*var(--r));
  left:calc(50% - 2*var(--r));
  top: calc(50% - 2*var(--r));
  --c1:radial-gradient(circle,red 50%   ,transparent 60%);
  --c2:radial-gradient(circle,orange 50%,transparent 60%);
  background:
    /*4 reds*/
    var(--c1),var(--c1),var(--c1),var(--c1),
    /*4 oranges*/
    var(--c2),var(--c2),var(--c2),var(--c2); 
  
  background-size:calc(var(--r)/3) calc(var(--r)/3); 
  background-position:
    calc(50% - var(--r)) calc(50% - var(--r)),
    calc(50% + var(--r)) calc(50% - var(--r)),
    calc(50% - var(--r)) calc(50% + var(--r)),
    calc(50% + var(--r)) calc(50% + var(--r)),
    calc(50% +  0px) calc(50% + var(--r)*1.414),
    calc(50% + var(--r)*1.414) calc(50% +  0px),
    calc(50% - var(--r)*1.414) calc(50% +  0px),
    calc(50% +  0px) calc(50% - var(--r)*1.414);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transform:scale(0);
}
.magic i::after {
  background-size:calc(var(--r)/5) calc(var(--r)/5);
  transform:rotate(55deg) scale(0);
}

.magic:hover:after {
  transform:scale(1);
  opacity:0;
  background-size:0 0;
  transition:
    transform 0.5s 0.5s,
    opacity 0.4s 0.9s,
    background-size 0.5s 0.9s;
}
.magic:hover i:after {
  transform:rotate(55deg) scale(1);
  opacity:0;
  background-size:0 0;
  transition:
    transform 0.5s 0.5s,
    opacity 0.4s 0.9s,
    background-size 0.5s 0.9s;
}

/**/
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css">
<span class="magic" style="--r:80px;">
<i class="fas fa-star fa-10x"></i>
</span>
<span class="magic">
<i class="fas fa-user fa-5x"></i>
</span>
<span class="magic" style="--r:20px;">
<i class="far fa-bell fa-3x"></i>
</span>
```

В основном, переменная `r` будет определять радиус всей фигуры, и вы можете легко изменить ее в зависимости от размера вашей иконки.

Comment: Шикарно! Спасибо за пошаговые пояснения!

Comment: @Misha Saidov Вот тема, которая набирает популярность на забугорных ресурсах. В ответе всё разжевано до мелочей, но на CSS/ Возьмешься сделать тоже самое, чисто на `JS` , как отдельную библиотеку., которую можно было бы применять на разных изображениях. Думаю будет очень популярно. Вверху дал ссылку на подобную работу, но уверен, что у тебя получится лучше  [spark animation](https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/xwJmgv)